# curl - get redirect url after waiting for few seconds

Tags: php, linux, redirect, curl, page-curl

I am able to get redirected url using below curl command.

```
      curl -Lks -o /dev/null -w  "%{url_effective}" https://www.testpp.com
```

But I have a case where page loads with 200 status, but after 2 or 3 seconds, page gets redirected.
Curl is giving me a response of 200 for the original url, but there is a 301 redirect which happens after the few seconds wait.

Is there a way i can get curl to trace out the final redirect?

Comment: What kind of code is that? Is it shellscript? Why `php` tag?

Comment: the redirect is perhaps js based?,

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way the page could redirect after x seconds is using JavaScript.  Curl can only follow http redirects.